# Showing 403 forbidden error on removing members of discord server in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, discord, bots

```
 $discord = new DiscordClient(['token' => 'OTIzMDg2MTgzNDg2MDYyNjQz.YcK5AA.HfoDRu-6sKDUPnneA29m3eHQtT4']);
 $users = $discord->guild->listGuildMembers(['guild.id' =>923083706934120448, 'limit' => 25]);
 $discord->guild->removeGuildMember(['guild.id'=>923083706934120448,'user.id'=>894299782481334302]);
```

**There was an error executing the removeGuildMember command: Client error: `DELETE https://discord.com/api/v6/guilds/923083706934120448/members/894299782481334302` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:**

> When I am kicking a member from server it is giving me forbidden error
> I have use Restcord library in this I have fetched the members through
> it ,And it is working prperly but when i am removing member it is
> giing me forbidden error   I have given permission to my bot through
> oath url generator but still it is givig me this error if you any idea
> about this i can explain more you can ask me?

Comment: Did you just post your discord token? Or did you remember to modify it before posting? If you did not modify it, I suggest resetting it right now as you just compromised your own token. Deleting this question will not be enough.

Comment: that is not the issue for me now i am using demo account did you have any suggestion for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue actually I have not given role to my bot in my server that is why it was showing forbidden cause it does not have permission to kick other users